# Multiclass classification error metrics in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

Is it possible to find the error metrics(precision and recall) in a multiclass classification problem in Apache Spark. I am using Logistic Regression from Spark's MlLib to build my model and want to evaluate my model using the error metrics.

Answer (score 1):

From [MLlib docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#label-based-metrics)

Assuming your test data is in `test`

> ```
> import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
> import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
> import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
> import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
>
> val predictionAndLabels = test.map { case LabeledPoint(label,
>    features) =>
>      val prediction = model.predict(features)
>      (prediction, label)
> }
>
> val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
> ```
>
> Confusion matrix
>
> ```
> println("Confusion matrix:")
> println(metrics.confusionMatrix)
> ```
>
> Overall Statistics
>
> ```
> val accuracy = metrics.accuracy
> println("Summary Statistics")
> println(s"Accuracy = $accuracy")
> ```
>
> Precision by label
>
> ```
> val labels = metrics.labels
> labels.foreach { l =>
>   println(s"Precision($l) = " + metrics.precision(l))
> }
> ```
>
> Recall by label
>
> ```
> labels.foreach { l =>
>   println(s"Recall($l) = " + metrics.recall(l))
> }
> ```
>
> False positive rate by label
>
> ```
> labels.foreach { l =>
>   println(s"FPR($l) = " + metrics.falsePositiveRate(l))
> }
> ```
>
> F-measure by label
>
> ```
> labels.foreach { l =>
>   println(s"F1-Score($l) = " + metrics.fMeasure(l))
> }
> ```
>
> Weighted stats
>
> ```
> println(s"Weighted precision: ${metrics.weightedPrecision}")
> println(s"Weighted recall: ${metrics.weightedRecall}")
> println(s"Weighted F1 score: ${metrics.weightedFMeasure}")
> println(s"Weighted false positive rate: ${metrics.weightedFalsePositiveRate}")
> ```

Comment: Ok Thanks. This is using the RDD API I guess. Is there a way to do the same thing using the DataFrame API as it is much more optimised.

Comment: AFAIK there is only RDD based API for this, I could be very well wrong

Comment: @RajnilGuha if you needed the dataframe API, you should have clarified this in your question, plus you should have provided what you have tried so far (from which, arguably, the API used would be apparent). I hope it is now clear why such 3-line "questions" get closed and downvoted...

Comment: @naveenmarri there is indeed a [`MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator) in Spark ML providing weighted precision & recall; check also the [docs for tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-tuning.html)

Comment: @desertnaut I have tested my model on training data and applied it on test data to get the predictions. I now want  to evaluate my model so would like to get the error metrics. Till now I haven't yet tried anything as far as error metrics is concerned.

Comment: @RajnilGuha an attempt can very well be *that's my code so far, and from this point I need to compute this & that...* Otherwise you expect someone to come up with an end-to-end scenario of his/her own, which may or may be not appropriate for your case - actually this is exactly what happened here, with a respondent spending time to *help* you, only to be told afterwards "that's nice, but I don't want it for the RDD API" (and not even getting an upvote as an elementary courtesy for the time spent)...